# How to securely run a Minecraft server on a local machine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

EDIT: I am using cubecoders AMP to run multiple instances

I am looking to set up a public Minecraft server (well multiple off one machine actually). I am wondering if there is a way in which I can ensure security on my home network? I have seen mentions of allowing only Minecraft to access a port and nothing else but I have no idea how I would do such a thing.

I won't be giving out my public IP as I have sub-domains which they will enter into their MC client to connect. But I imagine they would still have access to my public IP. Will portforwarding 25565 on my router allow anything to use that port or JUST the server and is this a secure method of preventing hacking or any information on my personal computer being stolen

Comment: Secure against what?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting your origin IP behind [CloudFlare Spectrum](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-spectrum/minecraft/) (think: CloudFlare but for Minecraft* instead of websites), then your only other worry is ensuring you don't run malicious plugins or mods.

*Or any non-HTTP service, actually

Comment: Just had a look at this and how people set it up etc, it seems pretty much the same is routing my IP through my domains with DNS anyway? Is there any additional benefit to cloduflare than how I've already set it up. Accessing my server now requires the domain instead of IP. Is cloudflare capable of masking my IP when they are connected or something?

Comment: Yes, that is literally what Cloudflare does; it forces people to connect through it (a proxy) instead of connecting directly to your home network. Also, no; DNS is basically assigning a human-readable name to an IP address; so, if your domain records point to your home IP, it's no different than just telling everyone that IP in terms of protection, just that it'd be easier/harder to remember. So, Spectrum is basically not-HTTP support.